# How to build unique constraints in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, constraints

I been trying to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29313646/1129332) example on how to build constraints in SQLite.

I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `user_id`   INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    `row_id`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    unique (user_id, row_id)
)
```

Than I been trying to make an insertions:

- `insert into users(user_id, row_id) values(1, 13)`
- `insert into users(user_id, row_id) values(2, 13)`

On the second insertion query it failed with the next message:

> UNIQUE constraint failed: users.user_id: insert into users(user_id,
>   row_id) values(2, 13)

I want to allow the next rows:

```
1,13
2,13
1,5
```

And disallow those

```
1,13
1,13
```

Answer (score 1):

`PRIMARY KEY` is by design `UNIQUE` and `NOT NULL` so `user_id` has to be `UNIQUE`.

Then you have `UNIQUE` constraint on columns `user_id` and `row_id`.

---

You could use composed `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `user_id`   INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `row_id`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, row_id)
);

INSERT INTO users(user_id, row_id) VALUES(1, 13);
INSERT INTO users(user_id, row_id) VALUES(2, 13);
INSERT INTO users(user_id, row_id) VALUES(1, 5);

INSERT INTO users(user_id, row_id) VALUES(1, 13);
-- Error: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.user_id, users.row_id
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/bbe23/1/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Primary Key is causing the issue, once a column is defined as primary it cannot be duplicated. Please try dropping the Primary Key.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`user_id`   INTEGER AUTO INCREMENT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
`row_id`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
unique (user_id, row_id)
```

)