# How to clear all entries from a SQLite table before adding new data?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm trying to clear all entries from 'Articles' table in order to prevent duplicate data... I've tried dropping the table if it already exists, but that did not work, the table did not get deleted which resulted in duplicate entries in the table.....

I've tried to clear all entries from the table 'Articles' before inserting new data...   but issue I'm currently having is that there I still a single entry in the table. There should be  3 entries.

I'm trying to empty the 'Articles' table at the start of 'addArticle'.

So I'm trying to:
1) Delete all entries in Articles Table
2)Add new Entries to Articles table

Please code below:

```
public class SQLiteDatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mytubeDb";
    private static final String TABLE_NAME = "Articles";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String KEY_URL= "url";
    private static final String[] COLUMNS = { KEY_ID, KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESCRIPTION,
            KEY_URL };

    public SQLiteDatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        String CREATION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME +" ( "
                + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + "title TEXT, "
                + "description TEXT, " + "url TEXT )";
        db.execSQL(CREATION_TABLE);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // you can implement here migration process
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
        this.onCreate(db);
    }



    public Article getArticle(int id) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_NAME, // a. table
                COLUMNS, // b. column names
                " id = ?", // c. selections
                new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, // d. selections args
                null, // e. group by
                null, // f. having
                null, // g. order by
                null); // h. limit

        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();


            Article article = new Article();
            article.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
            article.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
            article.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));
            article.setUrl(cursor.getString(3));

            return article;

    }

    public List<Article> allArticles() {

        List<Article> articles = new LinkedList<Article>();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        Article article = null;

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                article = new Article();
                article.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                article.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                article.setDescription(cursor.getString(2));
                article.setUrl(cursor.getString(3));
                articles.add(article);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        return articles;
    }

    public void addArticle(Article article) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ///// TRYING TO CLEAR ALL RECORDS BEFORE ENTERING NEW ONES
        String Delete = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
        db.execSQL(Delete);


        values.put(KEY_TITLE, article.getTitle());
        values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, article.getDescription());
        values.put(KEY_URL, article.getUrl());
        // insert
        db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, values);
        db.close();
    } ContentValues values = new ContentValues();



    }
```

Activity

```
 private SQLiteDatabaseHandler db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_journey_entertainment);


        db = new SQLiteDatabaseHandler(this);
        // create some players
        Article article1 = new Article(1, "THIS IS NEWS", "NEWS DESCRIPTION", "url1");
        Article article2 = new Article(2, "THIS IS MORE NEWS", "NEWS DESCRIPTION1", "url2");
        Article article3 = new Article(3, "EVEN MORE NEWS", "DESCRIPTION3", "url3");
        // add them
        db.addArticle(article1);
        db.addArticle(article2);
        db.addArticle(article3);


        // list all ARTICLES
        List<Article> articles = db.allArticles();

        if (articles != null) {
            String[] itemsTitle = new String[articles.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < articles.size(); i++) {
                itemsTitle[i] = articles.get(i).toString();
            }

            // display like string instances
            ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, itemsTitle));



        }
```

Comment: "but that did not work..." Please explain in more detail what happened with each attempted solution.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice.. Update question with further details.

Comment: put the code when you call to the sqlite class

Comment: Your description is wrong; you are not clearing the table before inserting all the data, but before inserting each record.

Comment: @diegoveloper  Updated question....

Comment: @CL    so I am and the 3 delete occurs before my final INSERT.. so that explains the single remaining table entry....  Thanks

Comment: If all you are concerned with is 'how to prevent duplicate entries' then there are cleaner solutions to this problem than deleting all the data and then replenishing it. Take a look at this solution :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312882/sqlite-preventing-duplicate-rows

Comment: yes, declaring a primary key

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the DELETE appears to be not working is due to logic as opposed to the DELETE not working. You delete all the rows from the table each time you call/invoke the `addArticle` method and then add 1 row. As such you will only end up with 1 row in the table.

One solution would be to delete all rows before adding any articles e.g. :-

```
    db = new SQLiteDatabaseHandler(this);
    // delete all rows
    db.getWriteableDatabase().delete("Articles",null,null); //<<<<<<<<
    // create some players
    Article article1 = new Article(1, "THIS IS NEWS", "NEWS DESCRIPTION", "url1");
    Article article2 = new Article(2, "THIS IS MORE NEWS", "NEWS DESCRIPTION1", "url2");
    Article article3 = new Article(3, "EVEN MORE NEWS", "DESCRIPTION3", "url3");
    // add them
    db.addArticle(article1);
    db.addArticle(article2);
    db.addArticle(article3);
```

**Along with removing the row delete code from the `addArticle` method.**

which would then be something like :-

```
public void addArticle(Article article) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    values.put(KEY_TITLE, article.getTitle());
    values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, article.getDescription());
    values.put(KEY_URL, article.getUrl());
    // insert
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, values);
    db.close();
}
```

---

An alternative approach (assuming that you aren't changing the data to be inserted) could be to only invoke the `addArticles` method when the table is empty, again along with removing the row deletions code from the `addArticle` method e.g.

e.g. you could have :-

```
    db = new SQLiteDatabaseHandler(this);
    Article article1 = new Article(1, "THIS IS NEWS", "NEWS DESCRIPTION", "url1");
    Article article2 = new Article(2, "THIS IS MORE NEWS", "NEWS DESCRIPTION1", "url2");
    Article article3 = new Article(3, "EVEN MORE NEWS", "DESCRIPTION3", "url3");
    if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db.getWriteableDatabase(),"Articles") < 1) {
        // add them
        db.addArticle(article1);
        db.addArticle(article2);
        db.addArticle(article3);
    }
```

Note! you could affect a change to the data by deleting the App's data, which is yet another way of clearing the table (actually removing the database entirely).

---

In the above `db.getWriteableDatabase()` has been used for the sake of breviity, you would probably move/convert such statements into methods within `SQLiteDatabaseHandler`

e.g. you might have :-

```
    public void deleteAllAtricles() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWriteableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME,null,null);
        db.close();
    }

    public long getArticleCount() {
        long rv;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWriteableDatabase();
        rv = DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,TABLE_NAME);
        db.close();
        return rv;
    }
```

If your end goal is to always prevent duplicates say of the url for the article then you could add a UNIQUE constraint.

You could use :-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME +" ( "
            + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + "title TEXT, "
            + "description TEXT, " + "url TEXT UNIQUE )";
    db.execSQL(CREATION_TABLE);
}
```

or

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    String CREATION_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE "+ TABLE_NAME +" ( "
            + "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + "title TEXT, "
            + "description TEXT, " + "url TEXT, UNIQUE(url)) ";
    db.execSQL(CREATION_TABLE);
}
```

The subtle difference is that in the former the unique constraint is defined within the column, whilst the latter defines the constraint at the table level (this it needs to be told what column(s)).

If there is a duplicate then `db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null, values);` will return -1 as a long (otherwise the rowid is returned as you have `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`, id is an alias for rowid ). You may also wish to do way with AUTOINCREMENT as per [SQLite Autoincrement](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html)  and instead just code `id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY`.