# SQLite: Prevent insertion of duplicate rows without failing

Tags: sqlite, primary-key, unique-constraint

I've read [the question/answer for preventing duplicate rows in a SQLite table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312882/sqlite-preventing-duplicate-rows) that advises placing a constraint on the necessary columns.  However, as I understand it, if I'm inserting a number of rows, such as in

```
insert into tableA
select *
from tableB
```

and one of them violates the constraint, the entire insert operation would fail.

Is there a way to avoid duplicates that would allow rows that don't violate the constraint to be inserted, while rows that do violate the constraint aren't?

My "naive" method is to inner join between source data and my destination table based on my columns that need to be unique, and remove the rows from my source data that match, but I'm wondering if there's a way to do this that let's me throw any number of rows at my destination table without having to add an extra step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with [`INSERT OR IGNORE INTO`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html)....:

```
create table tableA(
  col1 int, 
  col2 text unique
);
insert into tableA(col1, col2) values
(1, 'a'), (2, 'b');

create table tableB(
  col1 int, 
  col2 text unique
);
insert into tableB(col1, col2) values
(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c');

insert or ignore into tableA(col1, col2) 
select col1, col2 
from tableB;

select * from tableA;
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oR2Uc1P6Txy3ZBDnhKz4Kt/0).
Results:

```
| col1 | col2 |
| ---- | ---- |
| 1    | a    |
| 2    | b    |
| 3    | c    |
```

Answer (score 0):

You may using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` which uses exists logic to check if a duplicate would already exist:

```
INSERT INTO tableA (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM tableB b
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tableA a WHERE a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2);
```

This assumes that a "duplicate" is determined by two or more records having the same values for `col1` and `col2`.  You may adjust this logic as necessary.  The basic idea is that the entire select should run, excluding only those records which you know would cause the constraint to fail.

Comment: This is the "naive" method I mentioned in my post, which would definitely work, but I'm wondering if there's a way that doesn't rely on the user to check for duplicates before hand, ie a way for SQLite itself to keep the right rows and discard the others.  This in effect renders the constraint meaningless because it prevents the error that the constraint exists for.  I suppose my question is one of error handling?

Comment: Perhaps to further clarify, I'm thinking of this in an object-oriented programming way - a row might generate an exception, but you catch the exception and allow it continue handling the other rows, if that makes sense.  If that's literally not possible in SQLite than this is the correct answer, but I wanted to be sure.

Comment: You either use my answer, insert records one at a time (i.e. one transaction per attempted insert), or you insert in bulk, and rollback everything in case of even one constraint violation.  These are your options to my knowledge.

Comment: Note that your constraint isn't useless; it still guarantees that no one can violate the unique restrictions you have on your data.  It just so happens it might make inserting lots of data more challenging.